# httpclient ssl certificate on android

Tags: android, ssl, certificate, httpclient

I have some troubles with ssl using httpclient on android i am trying to access self signed certificate in details i want my app to trust all certificates ( i will use ssl only for data encryption). First i tried using this guide http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/sslguide.html on Desktop is working fine but on android i still got javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificate. After searching in google i found some other examples how to enable ssl.

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/62d856cdcfa9f16e - Working when i use URLConnection but with HttpClient still got the exception.

http://www.discursive.com/books/cjcook/reference/http-webdav-sect-self-signed.html - on Desktop using jars from apache is working but in android using included in SDK classes can't make it work.

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hc-httpclient-users/200808.mbox/%3C1218824624.6561.14.camel@ubuntu%3E - also get the same exception

So any ideas how can i trust all certificates on android using HttpClient

Comment: *"I want my app to trust all certificates..."* - Very bad idea. Its downright dangerous: [The most dangerous code in the world: validating SSL certificates in non-browser software](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~shmat/shmat_ccs12.pdf).

Answer (score 9):

If you happen to look at the code of DefaultHttpClient, it looks something like this:

```
   @Override
    protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {
        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(
                new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        registry.register(
                new Scheme("https", SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));

        ClientConnectionManager connManager = null;     
        HttpParams params = getParams();
        ...
    }
```

Notice the mapping of https scheme to org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory().

You can create a custom implementation for `org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SecureProtocolSocketFactory` interface (http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/protocol/SecureProtocolSocketFactory.html) wherein, you can create `java.net.SSLSocket` with a custom `TrustManager` that accepts all certificate.

You may want to look into JSSE for more details at http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html

Comment: org.apache.commons.httpclient.contrib.ssl. EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory is implementation of SecureProtocolSocketFactory which must trust all certificates. In apache guide is set like this
Protocol.registerProtocol("https", new Protocol("https", new MySSLSocketFactory(), 443)); as i mentioned i tried this but still don't work. Is this what you means or something else ?

Comment: What's the TrustManager associated with "MySSLSocketFactory" ?

Comment: public class NaiveTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {
 private static final X509Certificate[] _AcceptedIssuers = new X509Certificate[] {};

 public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
   throws CertificateException {
 }

 public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
   throws CertificateException {
 }

 public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
  return _AcceptedIssuers;
 }
}

Comment: Hmmm... the implementation looks good. Try logging and see the output - "-Djava.net.debug=all"

Answer (score 3):

The key idea is to use a customized SSLSocketFactory implementing LayeredSocketFactory. The customized socket doesn't need to HostNameVerifier.

```
private static final class TrustAllSSLSocketFactory implements
    LayeredSocketFactory {

    private static final TrustAllSSLSocketFactory DEFAULT_FACTORY = new TrustAllSSLSocketFactory();

    public static TrustAllSSLSocketFactory getSocketFactory() {
        return DEFAULT_FACTORY;
    }

    private SSLContext sslcontext;
    private javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory socketfactory;

    private TrustAllSSLSocketFactory() {
        super();
        TrustManager[] tm = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                String authType) throws CertificateException {
                // do nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                String authType) throws CertificateException {
                // do nothing
            }

            @Override
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }

        } };
        try {
            this.sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance(SSLSocketFactory.TLS);
            this.sslcontext.init(null, tm, new SecureRandom());
            this.socketfactory = this.sslcontext.getSocketFactory();
        } catch ( NoSuchAlgorithmException e ) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,
                "Failed to instantiate TrustAllSSLSocketFactory!", e);
        } catch ( KeyManagementException e ) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,
                "Failed to instantiate TrustAllSSLSocketFactory!", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port,
        boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) this.socketfactory.createSocket(
            socket, host, port, autoClose);
        return sslSocket;
    }

    @Override
    public Socket connectSocket(Socket sock, String host, int port,
        InetAddress localAddress, int localPort, HttpParams params)
        throws IOException, UnknownHostException, ConnectTimeoutException {
        if ( host == null ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Target host may not be null.");
        }
        if ( params == null ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Parameters may not be null.");
        }

        SSLSocket sslsock = (SSLSocket) ( ( sock != null ) ? sock
            : createSocket() );

        if ( ( localAddress != null ) || ( localPort > 0 ) ) {

            // we need to bind explicitly
            if ( localPort < 0 ) {
                localPort = 0; // indicates "any"
            }

            InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress(localAddress,
                localPort);
            sslsock.bind(isa);
        }

        int connTimeout = HttpConnectionParams.getConnectionTimeout(params);
        int soTimeout = HttpConnectionParams.getSoTimeout(params);

        InetSocketAddress remoteAddress;
        remoteAddress = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);

        sslsock.connect(remoteAddress, connTimeout);

        sslsock.setSoTimeout(soTimeout);

        return sslsock;
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        // the cast makes sure that the factory is working as expected
        return (SSLSocket) this.socketfactory.createSocket();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSecure(Socket sock) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        return true;
    }

}
```

You can then continue to use the customized SSLSocketFactory in the supported scheme registry.

```
private static final BasicHttpParams sHttpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
private static final SchemeRegistry sSupportedSchemes = new SchemeRegistry();
static {
    sHttpParams.setParameter("http.socket.timeout", READ_TIMEOUT);
    sHttpParams.setParameter("http.connection.timeout", CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
    sSupportedSchemes.register(new Scheme("http",
        PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    sSupportedSchemes.register(new Scheme("https",
        TrustAllSSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than accepting all certificates, I recommend this solution: [Trusting all certificates using HttpClient over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https/6378872#6378872)