# Android ICS: Problems to get the server certificate of the HttpsUrlConnection

Tags: android, ssl, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Since Android ICS we have problems to verify our certificates we are getting from the `HttpsUrlConnection`. In the earlier versions of android this was working well.
This is what we are trying to do:

```
BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier hostNameVerifier = new BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier();
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostNameVerifier);
URL url = new URL(serverUrl);
this.urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
this.urlConnection.connect();
hostNameVerifier.verify(urlConnection.getURL().getHost(),
(X509Certificate) urlConnection.getServerCertificates()[0]);
```

The exception which is thrown is:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException
>       at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.getCacheResponse(HttpEngine.java:412)
>       at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpUrlConnectionDelegate.getCacheResponse(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:390)
>       at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getServerCertificates(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:87)

Does somebody know what could have gone wrong and why it only persists since ICS?

Thanks!

----- Update -------
Now I made my own HostnameVerifier like this. I avoid the getServerCertificates()-method like this and it is working:

```
    public class MyHostNameVerifier implements HostnameVerifier {

    private String expectedHost;

    public MyHostNameVerifier(String expectedHost) {
        this.expectedHost = expectedHost;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        return expectedHost.equals(hostname);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to check out below links related to your problem.

http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html

[Android: HTTPS (SSL) connection using HttpsURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125275/android-https-ssl-conection-usign-httpsurlconnection)

[httpclient ssl certificate on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864016/httpclient-ssl-certificate-on-android)

```
KeyStore keyStore = ...;
 TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
 tmf.init(keyStore);
 SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
 context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
 URL url = new URL("https://www.example.com/");
 HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
 InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

Comment: The links are not helping me. My problem is only related with Android 4. On 2 and 3 they are working.

Comment: I think they made some modification in ICS..pleease look at link  http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html